# How to pythonically iterate two lists in an arbitrary order

Tags: python, list, iterable

I want to iterate over two lists in such a way that I can take an arbitrary number of values from one list and maintain my position in the other.

I've used indexes to store the current position in each list, then a while loop to go over them, but this definitely isn't very pythonic.

```py
def alternate_iterate(a,b,cond=lambda x, y : x > y):
    pos_a = 0
    pos_b = 0
    retval = []

    while(True):

        if(pos_a == len(a) and pos_b == len(b)):
            break

        if(pos_a < len(a) and cond(a[pos_a],b[pos_b])):
            retval += [a[pos_a]]
            pos_a += 1
        elif(pos_b < len(b)):
            retval += [b[pos_b]]
            pos_b += 1

    return retval

#example usage
print(alternate_iterate(['abc','abcd','ab','abc','ab'],
                        ['xy','xyz','x','xyz'],
                        cond=lambda x,y: len(x) > len(y))
```

This should print `['abc','abdc','xy','xyz','ab','abc','ab','x','xyz']`, where you don't have a perfect 1:1 alternating order. The order of the elements and the type of the elements should only depend on whatever `cond` is defined as.

Comment: Since you don't give values for the names `a` through `f` it takes rather a lot of effort to work out what you really need here.

Comment: yes what are the values of `a`, they can be strings like `'a'` since you're comparing strings and integers (impossible in python 3)

Comment: I have re-opened this since believe the `cond` function likely alters the solution needed (but without clarification, it might be closed again)

Comment: Also, expect trouble from the statement `b += 1`, since b is a list and this will therefore cause a TypeError when you try to increment it. Similarly with `a += 1`. I suspect these should operate on the respective `pos_*` names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more Pythonic way is usually to not use indexes at all and it is preferable not to use exceptions as a means of controlling "intended" program logic. You should also avoid unnecessary parentheses.

Here's how you could do it using iterators:

```
def merge(a, b, cond=lambda x, y : x < y):
    Done           = []
    iterA, iterB   = iter(a), iter(b)
    valueA, valueB = next(iterA, Done), next(iterB, Done)
    result         = []
    while not(valueB is Done and valueA is Done):
        if valueB is Done or valueA is not Done and cond(valueA, valueB):
            result.append(valueA)
            valueA = next(iterA, Done)
        else:
            result.append(valueB)
            valueB = next(iterB, Done)
    return result
```

This has the added benefit of making the function work efficiently with any iterable data as parameters.

for example:

```
print(merge(range(5, 10), range(7, 15)))

# [5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

It also makes it easy to create an iterator version of the function for lazy traversal:

```
def iMerge(a, b, cond=lambda x, y : x < y):
    Done           = []
    iterA, iterB   = iter(a), iter(b)
    valueA, valueB = next(iterA, Done), next(iterB, Done)
    while not(valueB is Done and valueA is Done):
        if valueB is Done or valueA is not Done and cond(valueA, valueB):
            yield valueA
            valueA = next(iterA ,Done)
        else:
            yield valueB
            valueB = next(iterB, Done)
```

**EDIT** Changed `None` to `Done` in order to let the function support None as a legitimate value in the input lists.

Comment: Excellent answer. `next(iterA,Done)` is a particularly good use of a little-known second parameter to `next()`. The iterator version of the function should be more prominent, in my humble opinion; an iterator is a more pythonic way to package this service than a function which returns a merged list.

Comment: more idiomatically, just use a plain object, so `Done = object()`, although the list *does* work

Comment: so long as `is` is consistently used for checks it doesn't matter what sentinel object is used. Use of `iter`'s second argument simplifies the code considerably.

Comment: It is important to guarantee that the sentinel is not one of the possible values.  This is achieved by using an object instance created within the function (Done). I was using None previously which didn't meet that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Summarising, you appear to want to take a value from one list or the other depending on the value of some predicate. Your existing logic doesn't appear to take into account the possibility of one of the lists being exhausted, at which point I've assume you would want to copy any remaining values from the other list.

Rather than using index values to select the successive list elements you can build an *iterator* on the list, and use the `next` function to get the next value.

In that case your logic would end up looking something like this:

```
def alternate_iterate(a_lst, b_lst, cond=lambda x, y: x > y):
    a_iter = iter(a_lst)
    b_iter = iter(b_lst)
    a = next(a_iter)
    b = next(b_iter)
    ret = []
    while True:
        if cond(a, b):
            ret.append(a)
            try:
                a = next(a_iter)
            except StopIteration:
                ret.append(b)
                for x in b_iter:
                    ret.append(x)
                return ret
        else:
            ret.append(b)
            try:
                b = next(b_iter)
            except StopIteration:
                ret.append(a)
                for x in a_iter:
                    ret.append(x)
                return ret


print(alternate_iterate(['abc','abcd','ab','abc','ab'],
                        ['xy','xyz','x','xyz'],
                        cond=lambda x,y: len(x) > len(y)))
```

the result I get is

```
['abc', 'abcd', 'xy', 'xyz', 'ab', 'abc', 'ab', 'x', 'xyz']
```

which would appear to be what you would expect.

As is often the case in such examples, you write more logic to handle the rarer corner cases (in this case, one list or the other becoming exhausted) than you do to handle the "happy path" where things proceed as normal.

Answer (score 0):

This version is using only iterators to achieve the functionality lazilly (which is Pythonic):

```
a = ['abc','abcd','ab','abc','ab']
b = ['xy','xyz','x','xyz']

cond=lambda x,y: len(x) > len(y)

def alternate_iterate(a, b, cond):
    a, b = iter(a), iter(b)

    def _return_rest():
        def _f(val, it):
            yield val
            yield from it
        return _f

    v1, v2 = next(a, _return_rest), next(b, _return_rest)

    while True:
        if v1 is _return_rest:
            yield from v1()(v2, b)
            break

        if v2 is _return_rest:
            yield from v2()(v1, a)
            break

        if cond(v1, v2):
            yield v1
            v1 =  next(a, _return_rest)
        else:
            yield v2
            v2 = next(b, _return_rest)

print(list(alternate_iterate(a, b, cond)))
```

Prints:

```
['abc', 'abcd', 'xy', 'xyz', 'ab', 'abc', 'ab', 'x', 'xyz']
```

Answer (score -4):

Put your lists into generators, and then you can call `next` on each one to get the next value. This answer isn't meant to be a complete solution, just to show how generators can produce values in any order with very simple, Pythonic code:

```
agen = iter(a)
bgen = iter(b)
print next(agen) # 'a'
print next(bgen) # 1
print next(bgen) # 2
print next(agen) # 'b'
```

and so on.

Comment: this ignores the condition and is quite far from generating an output list. `zip(agen, bgen)` would be a step in that direction, but insufficient by itself still

Comment: It's not meant to be a complete solution, just a demonstration of generators producing the values in the right order without any extra index variables.

Comment: and it isn't, which is why it should have really been a comment.